# sql express 2008 & tde

Tags: security, sql-server-express, tde

Good afternoon,

Anyone know if sql express 2008 version, the option of using TDE (Transparent Data Encryption).

I tried using it for testing and the server gave me the following error.

"The transparent data encryption is not available in the publication of this instance of SQL Server. See Books Online for more details on feature support in different editions of SQL Server."

Thanks and a greeting.

Answer (score 3):

TDE is available only in Enterprise editions AFAIK.

Comment: In the meantime I found the reference for the feature support: http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/product-info/compare.aspx (select all editions, then expand the "Enterprise Security" node).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, Microsoft supports TDE only in Enterprise Edition. However, there are several third party products that will provide TDE to all editions and verions of SQL Server, including SQL Express. One of those products being ours: [Encryptionizer for SQL Server](https://netlibsecurity.com). Another one that I am aware of is DBDefence. Internally they work very differently though: Encryptionizer sits between SQL Server and the Operating System, while DBDefence injects itself into the SQL process running in memory to change the behavior of the process.